# What are some easy but beautiful patterns in Pascal's Triangle?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics, big-list

Pascal's triangle has wide applications in Mathematics.I have seen that the most important applications relate to the binomial coefficients and combinatorics.

Are there some other beautiful **interesting patterns** in Pascal's triangle that can be found by selecting some other combination modes ?

Comment: Search in Google Images writing "Pascal's Triangle".

Comment: Also see [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjomrz1o-nOAhUMtY8KHQTXAZ8QFghcMAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cut-the-knot.org%2Farithmetic%2Fcombinatorics%2FPascalTriangleProperties.shtml&usg=AFQjCNFtuHU8o0hm0H09DMR1YbgpXRNvjA).

Comment: Why does the title ask about *applications* but the question ask about *patterns*? There are many applications that make use of the binomial coefficient properties one way or another, like e.g. describing [a deterministic Galton board](http://www-m10.ma.tum.de/ix-quadrat/?v=r_ho&s=1). Conversely, current answers tend to investigate patterns without neccessarily naming applications for them.

Comment: I suppose if the questions asked for actual _applications_, as the title suggests, then it would've been more well-received...

Answer (score 24):

How about Fibonacci sequence in the Pascal Triangle?
[image]

[Pascal's Triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PascalsTriangle.html) (from Wolfram MathWorld)

Answer (score 20):

> There is a nice *hexagonal* property in   the  Pascal   triangle:
>
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccc}
> &&&&&&&&1\\
> &&&&&&&1&&1\\
> &&&&&&1&&2&&1\\
> &&&&&1&&3&&3&&1\\
> &&&&1&&4&&6&&4&&1\\
> &&&1&&\mathbf{\color{blue}{5}}&&\mathbf{\color{blue}{10}}&&10&&5&&1\\
> &&1&&\mathbf{\color{blue}{6}}&&\mathbf{\color{red}{15}}&&\mathbf{\color{blue}{20}}&&15&&6&&1\\
> &1&&7&&\mathbf{\color{blue}{21}}&&\mathbf{\color{blue}{35}}&&35&&21&&7&&1\\
> 1&&8&&28&&56&&70&&56&&21&&8&&1\\
> \end{array}
>   The *hexagon* around $\binom{n}{k}$ fulfils
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{n}{k+1}\binom{n+1}{k}&=\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}\\
> \end{align*}

The  example  $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{6}{2}=\color{red}{15}$ shows
\begin{align*}
\binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{n}{k+1}\binom{n+1}{k}&=\binom{5}{1}\binom{6}{3}\binom{7}{2}=\color{blue}{5}\cdot \color{blue}{20}\cdot   \color{blue}{21}=2100\\
\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}&=\binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{1}\binom{7}{3}=\color{blue}{10}\cdot \color{blue}{6}\cdot \color{blue}{35}=2100
\end{align*}

> In  other words:
>
> - A *hexagon* around a binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ is always a *perfect square*. :-)

See *[Generalized hidden hexagon squares](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/12-1/gupta.pdf)* by A.K. Gupta for a generalized version of this relationship.

Comment: That's a truely remarkable property: _where else could you find hexagons that are perfect squares_?

Answer (score 12):

Pascal’s triangle reduced modulo $2$ is a discrete version of the [Sierpiński gasket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle); [this page](http://ecademy.agnesscott.edu/~lriddle/ifs/siertri/pascal.htm) is a very brief introduction, and [this page](https://oeis.org/wiki/Sierpinski's_triangle) at [OEIS](http://oeis.org) has a nice picture and some more information.

Comment: [This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93726541/Pascal/index.html) JS app I made will allow you to visualize the triangle under various different moduli. Enter modulo = 2 to get the version mentioned in this answer. For higher moduli, different colors represent different congruence classes, and monochrome mode shows zero congruence classes in black, and everything else in white (or possibly the opposite, I can't remember). The study of these diagrams easily reduces to the prime modulus case, for which there are some interesting patterns.

Answer (score 11):

> The one I like the most is associated to a very well known primality test: The number $n \gt 1$  in the second position (left or right) of a given line of the triangle is a prime number if and only if all the elements of the same line, except the first and last $1$'s, are divisible by it.

For instance:

$1,5,10,10,1$

$n=5$ and $5 \mid 10$, so $5$ is a prime number.

In other hand for instance:

$1,4,6,4,1$

$n=4$ and $4 \not\mid 6$ so $4$ is not prime.

$1,6,15,20,15,6,1$

$n=6$ and $6 \not\mid 15$, $6 \not\mid 20$ so $6$ is not prime as well.

All the elements must be divisible by $n$, if just one fails, it is not a prime number.

So performing the $\pmod{n}$ operation, the pattern at right side shows the rows of a prime $n$ as follows:

[image]

Comment: Nice observation! (+1)

Comment: So could you say the following: a number $n\ge2$ is prime iff $\sum_{i=0}^n (\binom{n}{i}\pmod n) = 2$ or iff $n \mid (\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i})-2$

Comment: Fun fact: this fact is a basis for how AKS primality testing algorithm (the first deterministic, provably polynomial-time general purpose primality testing algorithm) works.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way to extend Pascal's triangle; I think it's interesting.

In black we have the original Pascal's triangle. In green we have inserted rows between the black rows. To find the values, we use the polynomials which describe the slanted columns of the original triangle, shown in blue, and evaluate at half integers.
[image: Pascal plus]

So what's the point of this? Remember the numbers in Pascal's triangle also provide the binomial coefficients.

For example, $(1+x)^4=1+4x+6x^2+4x^3+x^4$.

These new rows also describe the coefficients of the series for binomials raised to the half integer power:
$(1+x)^\frac{7}{2}=1+\frac{7}{2}x+\frac{35}{8}x^2+\frac{35}{16}x^3+...$

Unlike the rows of Pascal's triangle, these continue forever. Also, like Pascal's tringle, the green numbers are the sum of the two green numbers directly above. For example, $\frac{15}{8}+\frac{5}{16}=\frac{35}{16}$.

Comment: Nice answer! (+1)

Comment: I feel like the term "[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)" should at the very least be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: My intuition tells me that this works for any complex x - producing the series expansion of the power operation. EDIT: @Wojowu that's exactly what I meant with that :)

Answer (score 6):

Here are some interesting facts about Pascal's triangle compiled from Google search.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

<sub>***All hail Google...***</sub>

Comment: The first image (gif) looks like babble to me. Looks like its author is trying to build some new theory out of it... Does anyone know whether it _really_ makes sense?

Comment: The same seems true for the second image; people building "new mathematics" or "new physics" often amuse me.

Comment: @Wojowu Blame the author.